# Route 53 / ELB not working under heavy traffic? Tips on health checks needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-route53

This is my setup on Amazon Web Services

- EC2 instances
- Autoscaling + loadbalancer
- Route 53 with A-record pointing to loadbalancer
- .fi-domain

This setup normally works fine. However, under heavy traffic mydomain.fi will occasionally not respond. The odd thing is, however, that connecting directly to the loadbalancer's public DNS  works fine.

In my mind the problem lies in one of the following:

1. The LB connects to unhealthy/not initialized instance
2. Problem with Route53 (misconfiguration?)
3. (Problem with the .fi-domain)

I guess the most likely problem is individual EC2 instances not working. I currently do not use any health checks to check if the instances are responding. Could this help? Any tips on best practice with this and Route 53 + LB?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would say the problem is precisely because you are not using any health checks. How can the ELB know if your ec2 instances are healthy and responding, if you have not setup healthchecks?

The fact that the problem only occurs during period of high activity only further points to the likelihood that this is your problem.

If you've gone to the trouble of setting up an ELB, you need to also setup the health checks so it get do what it is supposed to do - avoid sending traffic to node that can't handle it.

Comment: I now realized that "Your load balancer will automatically perform health checks on your EC2 instances and only route traffic to instances that pass the health check. If an instance fails the health check, it is automatically removed from the load balancer."


Ping Protocol: TCP

Ping Port: 80

Response Timeout: 5 Seconds

Health Check Interval:  0.5 Minutes

Unhealthy Threshold: 5

Healthy Threshold: 3


I haven't set up any other health checks, eg. for route 53.
Should I just edit these thresholds, or what's the recommendation?

Comment: Also, while I was having this problem, the instances all seemed healthy according to the "System reachability check" and the "Instance reachability check" in the instance list.

How come the LB's public DNS works? Is it just because it has randomly chosen another instance that happened to be working?

Comment: I've lost track of what your question is; you originally said you didn't have health checks enabled, and my answer attempted to help you with that. If that is no longer the question I'd suggestion you ask another question with all the relevant details and you will receive better advice. I don't completely understand/follow your comments above.

Comment: So apparently ELB automatically has health checks with the aforementioned parameters. My question is, should I add additional health checks or tweak the default values to ensure optimal performance?